# Finding it difficult with the following code

Tags: c#

I have written up to this place and am stuck I need help on how to terminate a program or continue .

What I mean is that when I ask the question would you like to withdraw today and if their response is NO then the program should terminate but if its YES it should continue.

What am I missing?
Please implement the aspect where by the program should terminate using the N for NO statement i didn't received the answer to that.

```
namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            int amount = 20000;
            int choice, pin = 0, x = 0;
            Console.WriteLine("Enter your pin");
            pin = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
            Console.WriteLine("welcome to HSPUIC bank would you like to make a withdraw today N or Y");
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What *is* the question?

Comment: If you want *this* program to terminate, just press "Enter".

Comment: You'll have to provide a better description of what you're trying to achieve. Please consider this: People will spend as much time to answer your question as you did asking it :)

Comment: like i ask a question would you like to make a withdraw if the answer is NO it should terminate or if the answer is YES it should continue

Comment: Did you look at the docs ?  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.console.readline%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

Comment: You should provide what you tried already, like how you approached parsing the input and the branching. In general questions in the form "please implement this for me" are not well received.

Comment: hello guys i tried this and it helped me but when i input else // if n program should terminate Console.WriteLine("Good Bye"); console.ReadLine(); the program won't terminate

Answer (score 2):

You are on the right track. What you are missing is to take and evaluate the user input - this is the information returned by the [Console.ReadLine method (as mentioned in the comments)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.console.readline%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) like this:

```
line = Console.ReadLine();
```

Your code could look like this:

```
int amount = 20000;
int choice, pin = 0, x = 0;
Console.WriteLine("Enter your pin");
pin = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
Console.WriteLine("welcome to HSPUIC bank would you like to make a withdraw today N or Y");
// save user input
var userInput = Console.ReadLine();
// evaluate if user wants to continue or not
if (userInput.ToLower() == "y")
{
    // if yes, go further
    Console.WriteLine("continue with other action...");
}
// else bye
Console.WriteLine("goodbye");
```

The line for the PIN already uses the user input! The same can be done with the question. If you want to *stay in the loop* until the user does not want to withdraw any more, than you need more than `if-else`. Take a look at the [iteration statements](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/32dbftby.aspx) like `do` and `while`.

A solution could look like this:

```
// user input = y or n
string choice;
// user pin
int pin = 0;
// state that indicates if the user wants to continue or not
bool continueLoop = false;
do
{
    // greet user
    Console.WriteLine("welcome to HSPUIC bank would you like to make a withdraw today N or Y");
    // take input
    choice = Console.ReadLine();
    // check if user has entered valid input
    if (choice.ToLower() == "y" || choice.ToLower() == "n")
    {
        // default decision is "user does not want to continue" = exit
        continueLoop = false;
        // user has choosen to continue
        if (choice.ToLower() == "y")
        {
            // user wants to do something, so stay in the loop
            continueLoop = true;
            // ask for pin
            Console.WriteLine("Enter your pin");
            var pinAsText = Console.ReadLine();
            //  convert the pin to number: if (int.TryParse(pinAsText, out pin)) ...
            if (pinAsText == "1234")
            {
                Console.WriteLine("PIN correct");
                // continue with logic here, for example take amount
            }
            else
            {
                Console.WriteLine("PIN incorrect");
            }
        }
    }
    else
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Please enter Y or N");
        continueLoop = true;
    }
} while (continueLoop);
Console.WriteLine("goodbye");
```

Now the flow looks like this:

```
welcome to HSPUIC bank would you like to make a withdraw today N or Y
>> Y
Enter your pin
>> 3
PIN incorrect
welcome to HSPUIC bank would you like to make a withdraw today N or Y
>> Y
Enter your pin
>> 1234
PIN correct
welcome to HSPUIC bank would you like to make a withdraw today N or Y
>> N
goodbye
```

Answer (score 2):

Certainly when your users have two different choice , you should use `if` in your program . Also you should save user's answer into a local variable to process it .

```
static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        int amount = 20000;
        int choice, pin = 0, x = 0;
        Console.WriteLine("Enter your pin");
        pin = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
        Console.WriteLine("welcome to HSPUIC bank would you like to make a withdraw today N or Y");
        char answer = char.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
        if (answer == 'Y')
        {
            //Code that must be executed after choosing "yes" .
            Console.ReadKey();
        }
    }
```

When you write nothing for "no" , your program will terminate .

Also you can use `string` instead of `char` :

```
string answer = Console.ReadLine();
        if (answer == "Y")
        {
            //Code that must be executed after choosing "yes" .
            Console.ReadKey();
        }
```

By the way, there are a lot of possible errors in your code (e.g. enter a character instead of integer for variable ' pin ') that must be handled by try-catch.